# Why do we have [hosting]?

Tags: discussion, scope, tags

Why do we have the tag [hosting](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hosting)? The excerpt reads:

> A service that runs Internet servers, allowing organizations and individuals to serve content to the Internet.

A good portion of the questions there have been closed, because they're from people seeking suggestions for a good hosting provider for their app/images/files.

The other questions look like they are inappropriately tagged (like [What is the maximum length of video on Facebook?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/40433/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-video-on-facebook)) and need to have the tag removed. (I'll start on some of those in a minute.)

Is there a question that would be on-topic for this site that would use that tag? To clarify, is there a legitimate use for this tag here?

For that matter, what about [web-hosting](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-hosting)? (No tag wiki.)

Answer (score 5):

Some of the questions seem reasonable, such as the one about using GitHub to host a website, among others:

- [How to use a github as a hosting for a small static website?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/22429/how-to-use-a-github-as-a-hosting-for-a-small-static-website)
- [How does Trello store my information?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/19120/how-does-trello-store-my-information)
- [Web video sharing service with “fair use” protection?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/6445/web-video-sharing-service-with-fair-use-protection)
- [Is there really no way to get JIRA Studio to work with Mercurial?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2484/is-there-really-no-way-to-get-jira-studio-to-work-with-mercurial)

These questions at least seem to be correct uses of the tag, as they are specific. Other questions with the tag seem to be recommendation type questions. Others don't seem to be about webapps at all, so the tag could certainly use cleaning up.